# Do I need duplicate website landing pages to correctly use SESSION

Tags: php, session

I am working on a project where some people will enter a website using a keycode landing page and some will go directly to the home page of the site - but their session will still be tracked.
If the user has a key code page they will go to the key code page then the landing page on through the site, and will be tracked with a Session.

But if there is no key code they will go to the landing page as an entry point where hits will be tracked through a php appended URL passed to the database (eg. www.xxxx.com?type=banner) and then on through the site, also tracked with a Session.

Normally you would start the login page by destroying the previous Session. But I can't put

```
session_destroy();
session_start();
```

on the landing page because it will destroy people who have logged in.

So my question is, can I use an "if" statement in the landing page? Will it work to say if there is a key code don't destroy this Session?  It seems rather cumbersome.

What about simultaneous submissions?  I see from reading other questions that this should not be a problem in PHP, but in this case what if someone goes to the key code page and someone else lands on the landing page at the same time?  Do I really have to build two separate websites?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, using an `if` in a landing page will work. And yes, it will be much, much easier than writing this entire question.

Comment: Simultaneous submissions won't be a problem, unless both requests use the same resources, for instance a file. There is no need to build separate websites for each user. I wonder how you planned to do that anyway.

Comment: why would you destroy the previous session on login?

Answer (score -1):

No, do that exactly.

Something like:

```
if (isset($_SESSION)) {
   if (!isset($_SESSION['important_var']) {
      $_SESSION['important_var'] = $some_value;
   }
} else {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['important_var'] = $some_value;
}
```

Comment: Checking `$_SESSION` before calling `session_start()` isn't going to be fruitful.

Comment: On a white board, yes; but what if auto_session_start is called in a config file?  What if other session action/checking is being done before this check?

I have no clue what else might be there.  Simply an example, not "you should do *exactly* this..."

Comment: Then this code may work but still doesn't address OP's problem at all.

Comment: I agree with GolezTrol. I'm trying to establish how and where to reset the Session.  I'm trying to figure out how to end a Session when the site I'm using has no end point - it's whenever the user leaves but it could be anywhere.  And it has two entry points, a login page or a home page.